# How to obtain a digital identity from the keychain?

Tags: ios, swift, security, keychain, ios13

I was following the tutorial by Apple: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/certificates/storing_a_certificate_in_the_keychain

and

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/identities/storing_an_identity_in_the_keychain

on how to store and retrieve an identity from the keychain.

Storing the identity seems to work fine, `errSecSuccess` is returned. However, when trying to obtain any identity, I get back `errSecItemNotFound` (or `-25300`).

Even dumping the keychain does not work as expected; after successfully adding an identity, `SecItemCopyMatching` still returns `errSecItemNotFound`.

See the following piece of code that pretty much matches the extract provided in the documentation:

```swift
// Store the digital identity in the keychain:
let addQuery: [String : Any] = [kSecClass as String: kSecClassIdentity,
                                kSecValueRef as String: identity,
                                kSecAttrLabel as String: "myid"]

guard SecItemAdd(addQuery as CFDictionary, nil) == errSecSuccess else {
    print("Could not store identity in keychain")
    return false
}

// Obtain the digital identity from the keychain:
let getQuery: [String : Any] = [kSecClass as String: kSecClassIdentity,
                                kSecAttrLabel as String: "myid",
                                kSecReturnRef as String: kCFBooleanTrue!]
var item: CFTypeRef?
let status = SecItemCopyMatching(getQuery as CFDictionary, &item)
guard status == errSecSuccess else {
    print("Could not find identity in keychain, OSerror: \(status)") // <---- -25300
    return false
}

let localIdentity = item as! SecIdentity

// [...]
```

For the sake of completion, this is how I "dump" the keychain (at least the identities):

```swift
let getQuery: [String : Any] = [kSecClass as String : secClass,
                                kSecReturnData as String  : kCFBooleanTrue!,
                                kSecReturnAttributes as String : kCFBooleanTrue!,
                                kSecReturnRef as String : kCFBooleanTrue!,
                                kSecMatchLimit as String : kSecMatchLimitAll]
var items: CFTypeRef?
let status = SecItemCopyMatching(getQuery as CFDictionary, &items) // <--- again, status = -25300
```

What's missing?

I went through the docs multiple times. Does storing items in the keychain take some time? If so, does the example provided by Apple mention that?

Why do I get an `errSecSuccess` when storing the item but it won't let me read the item right after?

I‘m also testing on a real device.

Comment: Sorry.. I didn't clear up what I meant.. Where is the code that creates the `identity` and why is it a string?

Comment: No worries; the identity gets imported from a p12 file. However, I thought that shouldn’t matter as SecItemAdd returned errSecSuccess. How come you think it’s a string? @Brandon It’s a SecIdentity.

Comment: When you retrieve the certificate from the keychain, you need to use `kSecClass: kSecClassCertificate`

Comment: Ah, are you sure? The Apple docs say sth different. It’s not a certificate that I‘d like to get from the keychain, it’s a digital identity. That’s both a cert and a private key. Why is that? I‘ll try though. @Brandon

Comment: Well then I'm very confused because the code shows `"mycert"` so I assumed it's a typo that you're storing as identity instead of a certificate.

Comment: That’s just a name, isn’t it? You shouldn’t be confused. P12 files are no certificates. I specified kSecClassIdentity. That’s not a cert. I changed the example accordingly. @Brandon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer myself.

> Using labels on an identity is tricky because identities are not stored in the keychain as an atomic item but are store as a separate private key and certificate, and those items use labels in different ways.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/98029

That is:

1. Pass `kSecReturnPersistentRef` to `SecItemAdd` when you add the identity to the keychain
2. Save the persistent reference wherever
3. Later on, when you need the identity back, call `SecItemCopyMatching` with that persistent reference

This makes sense and I was finally able to solve my problem this way.

Comment: It would be great if you could update your answer to include the example code like above. This documentation sure is dense appreciate you simplifying some of it!

Answer (score 1):

For those who get here like me after long hours hopefully this helps, NOTE I am newer to Swift so there are likely cleaner ways to do this:

Also see: https://github.com/emqx/CocoaMQTT/issues/573#issuecomment-1978191708

```
let certData = """
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGHDCCBASgAwIBAgIUInRnR2sNn9qV6Y...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIF/TCCA+WgAwIBAgICEAIwDQYJKoZ....
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

let privateKeyData = """
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKAIBAAKCAgEAxLNEyspSzJ9eSVX+h2P3kV6qH7...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
"""

func pemToCFDataArray(_ pemString: String, _ pemType: PEMType = .certificate) throws -> [CFData]? {
    var header = ""
    var footer = ""

    switch pemType {
    case .certificate:
        header = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----"
        footer = "-----END CERTIFICATE-----"
    case .privateKey:
        header = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"
        footer = "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"
    }

    // Split the PEM string into individual certificates
    let certificates = pemString.components(separatedBy: "\(footer)\n\(header)")

    guard !certificates.isEmpty else {
        throw "No certificates found in the PEM string"
    }

    var cfDatas: [CFData] = []

    for cert in certificates {
        // Remove PEM header and footer
        let pemBody = cert.replacingOccurrences(of: header, with: "")
                          .replacingOccurrences(of: footer, with: "")
                          .replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "")

        // Decode base64-encoded data
        guard let base64Data = Data(base64Encoded: pemBody) else {
            throw "Failed to decode base64-encoded data"
        }

        let cfData = base64Data as CFData
        cfDatas.append(cfData)
    }

    return cfDatas.isEmpty ? nil : cfDatas
}

// Add PrivateKey to KeyChain
guard let privateKeys = try pemToCFDataArray(privateKeyData, .privateKey) else {
  throw "Cannot convert privateKeyData to [CFData]"
}
for privateKeyData in privateKeys {
  let keyAttributes: [String: Any] = [
      kSecAttrKeyType as String: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
      kSecAttrKeyClass as String: kSecAttrKeyClassPrivate,
      kSecAttrKeySizeInBits as String: 4096
  ]
  guard let privateKey = SecKeyCreateWithData(privateKeyData, keyAttributes as CFDictionary, nil) else {
    throw "Cannot create SecKeyCreateWithData"
  }
  let addKeyQuery: [String: Any] = [kSecClass as String: kSecClassKey,
                                kSecValueRef as String: privateKey,
                                kSecAttrLabel as String: "key-\(userId)"]
  let addKeyStatus = SecItemAdd(addKeyQuery as CFDictionary, nil)
  guard addKeyStatus == errSecSuccess || addKeyStatus == errSecDuplicateItem else {
    throw "Failed to SecItemAdd addKeyStatus: \(addKeyStatus)"
  }

  print("Added key-\(userId) to KeyChain")
}

  // Add Certificates to KeyChain
  guard let certs = try pemToCFDataArray(certData) else {
    throw "Cannot convert certData to [CFData]"
  }
  for (idx, certData) in certs.enumerated() {
  guard let certificate = SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, certData) else {
    throw "Cannot create SecCertificateCreateWithData"
  }

  let addCertQuery: [String: Any] = [kSecClass as String: kSecClassCertificate,
                                    kSecValueRef as String: certificate,
                                    kSecAttrLabel as String: "cert-\(idx)-\(userId)"]
  let addCertStatus = SecItemAdd(addCertQuery as CFDictionary, nil)
  guard addCertStatus == errSecSuccess || addCertStatus == errSecDuplicateItem else {
    throw "Failed to SecItemAdd addCertStatus: \(addCertStatus)"
  }

  print("Added cert-\(idx)-\(userId) to KeyChain")
}

// Get Identity
let getIdentityQuery: [String: Any] = [kSecClass as String: kSecClassIdentity,
                             kSecAttrLabel as String: userId,
                             kSecReturnRef as String: kCFBooleanTrue!]

var item: CFTypeRef?
let identityQueryStatus = SecItemCopyMatching(getIdentityQuery as CFDictionary, &item)
guard identityQueryStatus == errSecSuccess else {
  throw "Failed to SecItemCopyMatching identityQueryStatus: \(identityQueryStatus.value)"
}
let identity = item as! SecIdentity
```